# Filtering data in an aggregation in a calculated field

Tags: tableau-api

I have 3 columns:

```
County | State | Population*
```

*(which is the population of that county)

How can I make a calculated field that displays what percent of the state's population is in each county?

If I do `([Population] / {SUM([Population])}) * 100` then that calculates each county's % of population of all counties in every state combined. I would like to calculate the `SUM[Population]` only where the state is the same state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Use the FIXED key word in your LOD calc.

```
sum([Population]) / sum({FIXED [State] : SUM([Population])}) * 100
```

Here's a good link for more information. https://interworks.com/blog/rcurtis/2016/03/24/tableau-deep-dive-lod-fixed-calculation/